# Circular Shebang #! (too many levels of symbolic links)

Tags: bash, shell, shebang

For context: I was reading [this](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sha-bang.html#FTN.AEN242) example of trickery one can do with a shebang. It uses

```
#!/bin/rm
```

which ends up deleting the file you executed (very funny; you can extend this to create self-deleting messages). This shows that the program (`rm`) is invoked with the filename as an argument and therefore has access to the whole file including the shebang that invoked it.

Another trickery I've come up with is to invoke yourself as an interpreter in shebang to create an infinite loop. For example if `/usr/bin/loop` starts with

```
#!/usr/bin/loop
```

t should invoke itself with itself forever. Obviously at some point an error will occur and in my particular case I get:

```
bash: /usr/bin/loop: /usr/bin/loop: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

It looks like it got two levels deep. Can somebody explain to me why this particular error occurs? Or maybe share some other error messages for different shells.

In particular I would like to understand why there are symbolic links involved and whether this is an implementation detail of bash or not.

Comment: I just noticed that the first part is not as relevant as I thougt for understanding what is happening (you might ignore it). For example I think you would still get an infinite loop if the shell removed the sha-bang and piped the rest of the file into the interpreter.

Comment: Nitpick: That's infinite recursion (`foo( foo( foo(...) ) )`), not an infinite loop (`for true { foo() }`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why this particular error occurs?

Because when kernel tries to run the executable, tries to run `/usr/bin/loop`, then tries to run `/usr/bin/loop`, then tries to run `/usr/bin/loop`, etc. and finally fails with `ELOOP` error. It checks that.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/exec.c#L1767

> hare some other error messages for different shells.

While it could be, this particular errno message comes from glibc `strerror`.

> why there are symbolic links involved

Because `ELOOP` is typically returned when doing input/output operations, the message mentions them.  Symbolic links are not involved.

> this is an implementation detail of bash or not.

Not.

Comment: The code you shared mentions "4 levels of binfmt rewrites". Does that mean that the shebang is evaluated four times? I suspected from the error message that it failed after 2 levels but that was just a guess based on the formatting.

Comment: `Does that mean that the shebang is evaluated four times?` I think so, yes.